# How to display integers as 6-digit values in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I format integers in a text_field so that they always consist of 6 digits?

So for example when the integer is stored as `1` in the database, in the text_field it would say: `000001`. The user should also be able to edit these values, yet not reduce or exceed the number of digits.

I tried something like this but it's not working for me:

```
def formatted_number(int)
  int.to_s.rjust(6, '0')
end
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why exactly that is not working for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use string formatting:

```
def formatted_number(int)
  '%06d' % int
end

formatted_number(123)
#=> "000123"
```

For the sake of readability you can also use the explicit call to `Kernel#format`:

```
def formatted_number(int)
  format '%06d', int
end
```

Refer to [the `Kernel#format` documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) for the syntax of the format string.

Comment: Basically, yes. But i think it is better style to use `String#format` (or how this is called) than fiddling with the string yourself. What if you decide to support float values, too, for example?